# Javascriptでのスクロールエフェクトの方法

Tags: javascript

現在html、css、Jacvasciptでサイトを作っています。

JQueryでのプラグインなどはたくさん見つかったのですがJavascriptではスクロールエフェクトは使えないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

jQuery自身がJavaScriptライブラリなので、何ら問題は無いですよ。

探せばこんなのが見つかります。

[CSS初心者にも簡単に使える！スクロールに連動するさまざまなエフェクトを実装できるスクリプト -AOS](https://coliss.com/articles/build-websites/operation/javascript/animate-on-scroll-library-aos.html)

[JS デモがめちゃ楽しい！jQuery不要でスクロールにあわせて要素をアニメーションで表示するスクリプト -WOW.js](https://coliss.com/articles/build-websites/operation/javascript/js-wow.html)
上記WOWの使用例多数
[任意の要素をスクロールフェードインアニメーションで表示しよう](https://digipress.info/members/expert-customize/use-scroll-fade-in-to-specific-object/)

jQuery使用も含みますが。
[手軽に実装！Webサイトにアニメーションを加えられるCSS＆JavaScriptライブラリー](https://www.webcreatorbox.com/tech/animation-libraries)

蛇足かもしれませんが。
[脱jQueryのためにしたこと](https://ics.media/entry/17451)